# Stata simulation from two distributions

Tags: stata

I'm trying to perform a simulation where I create a variable that has random numbers generated from a combination of two slightly different distributions. Using a loop - how do I specify the number to generate from each (say I want to generate `50` numbers from one distribution and `30` from another)? For example:

```
set obs 50

generate test = runiform()*20  

set obs 30

replace test = runiform()*100
```

If I run this as part of the loop I get:
obs must be between `50` and `2147483646`

I'm assuming I'm missing something basic, but not sure how to specify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set obs 80
generate test = runiform()*20  
replace test = runiform()*100 in 51/80
```

The reason your code does not work is that `set obs` expects the integer to be at least as large as the current number of observations.

You can modify your approach like this:

```
clear
set obs 50
generate test = runiform()*20  
set obs 80 // or try -insobs 30- 
replace test = runiform()*100 if missing(test)
```